# Make Navbar stick to the top after redirecting to another html with href

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I just finished learning the basics and trying to get some practice in. My problem is that I can't get the navbar/sidebar to stick at all times even after redirecting to another HTML.
How do I do that?

Thanks

I basically tried out any relevant video/source I had but they only show how to make a navbar/sidebar but not how to keep it after changing the page.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

* {
    font-family: "Google Sans Regular";
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100px;
    background: #191735;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Kalkulator/css/style.css">
    <title>TÜV i-sec</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="./Kalkulator/html/komponente.html#divof">Managed Security Service</a>
            <a href="">EPP Managed Service</a>
  </nav>
  </body>

  <script src="./Kalkulator/js/startInterface.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you use the property ```position: sticky``` for your navbar ?

Comment: The correct property would probably be [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed). Sticky only makes sense when initially the navbar is not at the top.

Comment: @Shirua the question is not very clear currently. Are you talking about the positioning of the navbar, or the fact that you do not want to repeat the code for the navbar in HTML? Could you try and provide a [minimal, reproducible example in code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I am new so it took me a while to figure it out. I edited the main post now and put in the code. the href redirects to another .html. When i press "Managed Security Service" it redirects me to that HTML but the navbar disappears.